# React Native - Focus a TextInput (Inside custom Component) that is inside of a Flat List element

Tags: react-native

I'm a React Native beginner and I'm working with a Flat List and custom Rows. Inside of each custom row, I have elements like Text, TextInput, and Button. The problem is that I need to press one of these buttons that enables and triggers a focus to the TextInput.

I tried implementing that with **refs** but everything freezes so I don't know how to do that correctly.

1. My constructor

```
class EditProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._rowRefs = {}
  }
```

2. My FlatList and MyCustomRow

```
_renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <MyCustomRow 
                       fieldname={item.fieldname}
                       value={item.value}
                       isEditable={item.isEditable}
                       editFieldHandler={ this.editFieldHandler }
                       allowsEdition={item.allowsEdition}
                       ref={ref => { this._rowRefs[index] = ref}}
                      />
    )
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <FlatList
          ref={this.flatListRef}
          style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.fields}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor= {this._keyExtractor}
          extraData={this.state.refresh}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

3. Trying to print the refs:

```
enableField(name) {
    console.log('Printing refs...')
    console.log(this._rowRefs) // the Button pressed freezes here
  }
```

I expect to see what's inside of _rowRefs, but instead of that, the button just gets frozen and I never see that result in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the key for each ref (not index)

```
ref={ref => { this._rowRefs['key1'] = ref}}
```

and invoke focus action like this:

```
this._rowRefs['key1'].focus()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried that, but the behavior remains the same, I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's need to work for `TextInput` element, you try to focus on `FlatList`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the above code after removing

```
console.log(this._rowRefs)
```